# How to put a predefined word between text in an Angular reactive form in a rich text editor?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, rich-text-editor

I want to put a selected predefined text in a rich text editor, which is received in `expression`, but I also don't want to replace all the text, instead, add the selected predefined text to the existing one from a selected part of the text. I know there is two methods in FormControl called `setValue()` and `patchValue()`, and, with a friend tried to put the selected predefined text creating a method like the one below:

```
onPutWord( expression : any ){
    this.demoForm.get('richTextareaInput')?.patchValue(   
       this.plantillaForm.value.richTextarea + expression;   
    );
}
```

Which by selecting the predefined text, it puts at the end of the general text, and also doing a line break:

Before insering the predefined text:

> This is a selected text: [Spot to put the text]. Neat.

After inserting the predefined text:

> This is a selected text: . Neat
> [Selected text]

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Hi, what about a replacement with a substring or regex ?.

Comment: What @RicardoMachado said should do the trick. Also, make sure the text you put in does not have any newline characters in it.
I'd also put it inside a subscription to `this.demoForm.get('richTextareaInput').valueChanges`